# Why does an empty string work in this example but this.state.foo doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, boolean, jsx

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

class TodoTextInput extends Component {
  state = {
    text: this.props.text
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    const text = e.target.value.trim()
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.props.onSave(text)
      this.setState({
        text: ''
      })
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleBlur = e => {
    if (!this.props.newTodo) {
      this.props.onSave(e.target.value)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input className={
             classnames({
               edit: this.props.editing,
               'new-todo': this.props.newTodo
               })
             }
             type='text'
             autoFocus='true'
             value={this.state.text}
             onChange={this.handleChange}
             placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
             onKeyDown={this.handleSubmit} />
    )
  }
}

export default TodoTextInput
```

When I run this code and start typing in the input field, I get the following error message in the console:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to
>   be controlled.

This leads me to believe that the value attribute sees this.state.text as null or undefined. However, the code works when I add || ' ' at the end of state.text to become:

```
text: this.props.text || ''
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does it work even though ' ' should translate to falsy too just
   like this.props.text?
2. Why does the value attribute see this.props.text as null or undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `this.state.text` is undefined (meaning `this.props.text` has been undefined). If the `value` prop of `input` is undefined, React considers the input as "uncontrolled".

You should fall back to empty string in the state initialization

```
state = {
  text: this.props.text || ''
}
```

to fix this or assign a [default value](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to `TodoTextInput`

```
TodoTextInput.defaultProps = {
  text: ''
}
```